# Speeding up a function with dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I have this program

```
//h is our N
    static int g=0;
    int fun(int h){
        if(h<=0){
                  g++;
                  return g;
                  }
    return g+fun(h-1)+fun(h-4);
    }
```

Is it possible to speed it up using dynamic programming?

I figured out that this function runs in O(2^n)

I am supposed to reduce the running time by dynamic programming, but do not understand the concept.

Just asking for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: @Michael I think @aristotaly is referring to that Big O notation thing-a-ma-jig.

Comment: hasn't homework tag been removed as all pseudo tags (useless by themselves to classify a question) ?

Answer (score 7):

While I can't give an answer to your actual question, I am intrigued by something altogether different, namely the statement

```
return g+fun(h-1)+fun(n-4);
```

Obviously, your function has the side effect of changing the global static variable `g`. I am not 100% sure whether the `return` statement's expression actually evaluates in a clearly defined fashion, or whether the result might be undefined.

It might be a nice exercise to think about the order in which those function calls are executed, and how this affects `g` and thereby the function's result.

Comment: isn't it somehow the question ? The whole point of the exercise seems to be removal of side-effect.

Comment: @kriss: the problem is, that in this code, the side effect doesn't actually yield a well-defined result.

Comment: @jplacek: yes, we have to choose a behavior between the possible ones before removing side effect (and what about effect of initial value of g). Defining the function mathematically would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

If we define that summation order in g+fun(h-1)+fun(n-4) is from left to rigth, than this is good defined problem. With that I get values for fun(n), n=1,...,15:

```
3, 6, 10, 15, 33, 74, 154, 295, 575, 1143, 2269, 4414, 8508, 16396, 31634
```

Return value of fun(n) is evaluated as sequence of summations with not-descending elements. Each summand is for one larger then previous (return g++;) or same as previous (return **g**+fun()+fun()). Execution sequence of return statements depend only of fun() input parameter. So, with g set to initial value != 0 we get same summands as with g=0, but every summand is larger for same initial value. 
With that, fun(n) with initial g > 0 will return value that is **g * number of executed return statements** larger than with initial g = 0.

Define A(n) as number of executed return statements while executing fun(n), and G(n)  number of executed return statement in **if** clause (same as number of g++ statement executions). For A and G holds:

```
A(n) = A(n-1) + A(n-4) + 1
G(n) = G(n-1) + G(n-4)
A(n) = 1 and G(n) = 1, for n <= 0
```

From these observations it can be seen that for n > 0 holds:

```
fun(n) = fun(n-1) + G(n-1) * A(n-4) + fun(n-4)
```

Simple python implementation:

```
def x( h ):
  Rg = { -3:1, -2:1, -1:1, 0:1 }
  Ra = { -3:1, -2:1, -1:1, 0:1 }
  F  = { -3:1, -2:1, -1:1, 0:1 }
  for i in xrange( 1, h+1 ):
    F[i] = F[i-1] + Rg[i-1]*Ra[i-4] + F[i-4]
    print i, F[i]
    Rg[i] = Rg[i-1] + Rg[i-4]
    Ra[i] = Ra[i-1] + Ra[i-4] + 1
```

@stakx: for expression g+fun(h-1)+fun(h-4) we can't have evaluation order guaranty, especially not in C.

Comment: if you try the C function, even with evaluation order not guaranteed, you can see your python function does not return the same results. There should be an error somwhere in your analysis. Are you sur fun return the number of return statements * g. Seems not obvious to me.

Comment: @kriss: assuming that g+fun(n-1)+fun(n-4) is evaluated from left to right, than fun(1)=0+fun(0)+fun(-3)=0+1+2=3. When I run this C implementation I get fun(1)=4. Changing line:

    return g+fun(h-1)+fun(h-4);

with lines:

    int aa = g;
    return aa+fun(h-1)+fun(h-4);

I get fun(1) = 3. Difference is probably in optimization.

Comment: yes. I got the same results once I forced evaluation order from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , It's possible to use DP to speed it up and avoid using CPU stack, but I agree with stakx about the side effect of changing the global static variable g.
It's better to provide a mathematical expression because the recursive function above could give a different result depending on the order & count of calls.

Answer (score 0):

OK. We start from fun (a serialized version where order of evaluation is forced).

```
int fun(int h){
    if(h<=0){
         g++;
         return g;
    }
    int tmp1 = g;
    int tmp2 = fun(h-1);
    int tmp3 = fun(h-4);
    return tmp1+tmp2+tmp3;
}
```

Let's focus on g and forget the current result of the function

Now it is easy to change the function to pass in g as a parameter and to return the new value of g as a result.

```
int gun(int h, int g0){
    if(h<=0){
         return g0+1;
    }
    int tmp1 = g0;
    int tmp2 = gun(h-1, g0);
    int tmp3 = gun(h-4, tmp2);
    return tmp3;
}

What can be simplified into:

int gun(int h, int g0){
    if(h<=0){
         return g0+1;
    }
    return gun(h-4, gun(h-1, g0));
}
```

Now back to fun:

```
int fun2(int h, int g0){
    if(h<=0){
         return g0+1;
    }
    return g0+fun2(h-1, g0)+fun2(h-4, gun(h-1,g0));
}
```

fun2 does exactly the same thing as the initial fun, but now as we removed the side effect and the function only depends from it's parameter, we can memoize results (store already computed results in an array), which should speed-up the computing.

We can still simplify gun a bit. The g0 parameter is not really necessary, let's set it to 0.

```
int gun2(int h){
    if(h<=0){
         return 1;
    }
    return gun2(h-4) + gun2(h-1);
}
```

We may even define a fun3 with g0 parameter fixed to 0, henceforth a bit simpler, but it still has to call fun2. I do not see yet how to simplify further but it's probably possible.

```
int fun3(int h){
    if(h<=0){
         return 1;
    }
    return fun3(h-1)+fun2(h-4, gun2(h-1));
}
```

Comment: in the second re-writing step, I was somewhat confused by `int tmp3 = gun(h-4, tmp2);`. Why do you pass in `tmp2` for parameter `g`? Moreover, since the function might change `g`, shouldn't the current value of `g` be returned, ie. shouldn't that function return a (two-)tuple?

Comment: @jpalecek: for speedup, once we have true functions without side effect memoizing (keeping values already computed) is easy (even if it can take some space). I do not understand what you speak about when you say "this doesn't work". My gun function is not supposed to compute the same thing as fun, but just to return the same value for g as it would have after setting it to 0 and calling the initial fun with side effects. gun clearly won't return the same value as fun. But you may be speaking of something else ? I may have made some mistake.